# http authorization with webdriver and popup window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to automatically login in to a site with a user-name and password. I've done my research and I don't believe this feature is supported by WebDriver, so I need to find another way. The site I'm trying to automate logging into is located [here](https://portal.adp.com/public/index.htm).

When prompted to login a popup window comes up that doesn't seem to be part of the browser. I'm using Firefox and Chrome. It seems Windows API may be required? I already tried passing the credentials in the URL but that didn't work.  Also tried sendkeys, but received a Windows exception that the application was not accepting Windows messages. I also tried switching the current `handle` using `driver.windowhandles` but the popup doesn't seem to be a new handle.

Does anybody have any ideas? I'm kinda stuck. The preliminary code to get to the popup window is:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.portal.adp.com");
string currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
IWebElement userLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("employee"));
userLogin.Click();
```

Comment: Just as an update, I was able to solve this problem. Previously I tried sendkeys butwas unable to get it to work correctly. I was using Sendkeys.sendWait(), to make the function wait before sending the keys, but it still had no effect. By putting Thread.sleep(2000) before Sendkeys.sendWait("text to put"), it works perfectly. Not sure why the thread.sleep statement was needed, because sendwait is supposed to cover that, but its what was needed

Comment: In addition I also tried the WebDriverWait() function, but it did not help either

Answer (score 4):

The popup you are seeing is prompted by web server and is a authentication prompt. Selenium doesn't support this operation.

One of the way to handle this limitation is to pass user and password in the url like like below:

`http://user:password@example.com`

More info  available here : http://aleetesting.blogspot.in/2011/10/selenium-webdriver-tips.html

Comment: Hi Satish, thanks for responding. I looked at the link you provided and was not able to make it work. I previously tried passing the user and password in the url. It didn't work, and just automatically forwarded me to the same homepage: portal.adp.com.  My username is of the form: user@mycompany.com, the username has the '@' symbol in it. Here are the url's I tried without success:

Comment: http://<user%40mycompany>:password@portal.adp.com/    http://user%40mycompany:password@portal.adp.com/  https://user%40mycompany:password@portal.adp.com/  https://user%40mycompany:password@portal.adp.com/login/   Have any ideas? I also tried using the Windows funtion sendkeys without success.

Comment: You are pointing to home page that's why you get home page after authentication. The login page in html view source is : `/wps/employee/employee.jsp`. So you must use : `https://user:password@portal.adp.com/wps/employee/employee.jsp`

Comment: Hi Satish, thanks so much! I have one more question- how did you find out what the login page was in html view? I'm just curious so I can figure that out in the future. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: As i mentioned : you can see the page link in 'html view source'. see the button tag properties in home page.

Comment: Yes Satish, here you go:                                    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.portal.adp.com");
            IWebElement userLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("employee"));
            userLogin.Click();

            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("user");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("password");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

Comment: Thank you John for this important info.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted my answer out there because I think I've solved it. This answer does not require passing the credentials through the URL (for those of you that are unable to like me). It also does not require any custom Firefox Profiles or extensions to be installed or included with the solution or installed onto the browser eliminating cross-machine compatibility issues.

The issue with me was that the authentication could not be completed via passing the credentials through the URL because the login was behind a proxy.

So, I turned to windows automation toolkits and found AutoIT. Using AutoIT and Selenium, you can login automatically by sending the username and password to the windows dialog that appears. Here's how (note the steps below are for c#:

1 - Download AutoIT from http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

2 - Add the autoit .dll to your project references.

Right click on references, select Add Reference. Next click the browse button and browse to the dll location (most default installations it will be c:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX3.dll), and add to project.

3 - use AutoIT and Selenium like this (assuming your web driver is already initialized):

```
    //Initialize AutoIT
    var AutoIT = new AutoItX3();

    //Set Selenium page load timeout to 2 seconds so it doesn't wait forever
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    //Ingore the error
    try
    {
      Driver.Url = url;
    }
    catch
    {
      return;
    }

    //Wait for the authentication window to appear, then send username and password
    AutoIT.WinWait("Authentication Required");
    AutoIT.WinActivate("Authentication Required");
    AutoIT.Send("username");
    AutoIT.Send("{TAB}");
    AutoIt.Send("password");
    AutoIT.Send("{ENTER}");

    //Return Selenium page timeout to infinity again
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
```

Anyway, that's it, and it works like a charm :)

Also note that there are some special characters that need to be escaped in AutoIT using the sequence "{x}". For example, if your password is "!tRocks", you'd need to pass it into AutoIT as "{!}tRocks".

Happy automating.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But I am having a problem. Setting Driver.Url doesn't actually browse to the page. It just stays a blank page. but when I use navigate().tourl it goes to the page but never executes the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
   profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", hostname);
   Driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

hostname is your URL (example.com) then try to

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://user:password@example.com);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got done working on a prototype project that is supposed to handle exactly this kind of situation.

It utilizes BrowserMob, a popular open source proxy, to perform the authentication.

[SeleniumBasicAuthWrapper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/seleniumbasicauthwrapper/?source=navbar)  Hope it helps!  It is still a work in progress, but hopefully we'll get any kinks or defects ironed out in the near future.